# Supermarket checkout python

Tags: python, checkout

I am trying to write a check out program but I dont' know what I am doing wrong on the while loop. Could someone help me?

`scanPrice`s function: First call the `readPriceList` function to read the price list from a text file. Display all items in the price dictionary. Then use a loop for the customer to enter product code of each item he wants. Every time a product code is entered, check to see whether the code is in the dictionary. If it is not, display “Item not found”. If the code is in the dictionary, display “Item found” and the price of the item. When the customer has no more product code to enter, he types “9999” to exit the loop. The `scanPrices` function will calculate, display and return the total price of all the items ordered.

```
def scanPrices():
    price_list = readPriceList()
    itemCode = 0
    totalPrice = 0
    while itemCode != 9999:
        itemCode = int(input("Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: "))
        if itemCode in price_list:

            print("Item found. Price:", )
        else:
            print("Item not found")
    totalPrice = totalPrice +
    print("Subtotal:$",totalPrice)
    return totalPrice
```

Comment: Is `price_list` a dictionary or a list?

Comment: Your not adding anything to total price, so it will always remain 0?

Comment: What is your expected output? What is your actual output? Also, it seems like your call to `print` in the first part of your if-statement is malformed. Oh and one more thing. You probably shouldn't mix CamelCase (itemCode) and lower_letters/PIP style (price_list). It's generally considered bad style and also makes me think that you are either schizophrenic or made some copypasta.

Comment: My while loop is not working so never stops when I enter a code, always says Item not found even for the code 9999 to stop.

Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: 1243 Item not found 
Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: 1423 Item found. Price: 7.88 Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: 2487 Item found. Price: 12.52 Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: 2368 Item found. Price: 5.25 Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: 9999 Total price: 25.65

Comment: price_list is a dictionary